# Linq query with Datetime Object

Tags: linq, datetime

I want to receive the newest item from a collection. Each item has a "DateTime" field (EditDate) and I do a little query like this:

```
var s = from l in OCollectionAgents
    where l.IDOfVehicle == agent.IDOfVehicle
    orderby
    agent.EditDate ascending
    select l;
```

Then after the query I do this:

```
agent.DetailInformationOfResults.NewestAgentEditDate = s.First().EditDate;
```

But no matter what, if the sort direction is **ascending** or **descending** I still get the same item. The oldest item.

I fixed the problem by doing this, and it worked.

```
agent.DetailInformationOfResults.NewestAgentEditDate = s.Max(d => d.EditDate);
```

But now, I wonder why does my query result not change the sort direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query `agent.EditDate` is a constant expression and will be the same for every item. Perhaps you want a join?

Comment: This is the problem - that you're not sorting the selected items.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers from [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063632/linq-query-with-datetime-object/2063665#2063665) and [orsol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063632/linq-query-with-datetime-object/2063664#2063664) look correct. I think you want to do following

> ```
> var s = from l in OCollectionAgents
>     where l.IDOfVehicle == agent.IDOfVehicle
>     orderby
>     l.EditDate ascending
>     select l;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to order by l.EditDate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to try like this.

var s = from l in OCollectionAgents

```
where l.IDOfVehicle == agent.IDOfVehicle
orderby
l.EditDate ascending
select l;
```